# How can I pull the number between <button>

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I have a python script that interacts with the nike webpage and I tried setting up a way to find and click the shoe size but the issue is that when I find by XPATH or CSS Selector the element changes depending on what sizes are available.

Ex: here is the xpath for a size 9.5 for one shoe

/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05jl0.png)/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05jl0.png)/span/ul/li[8]/button

and a size 9.5 for another shoe

/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05jl0.png)/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05jl0.png)/span/ul/li[7]/button

The XPATH element is different because certain sizes are available for one shoe while others aren't which is causing the element location to vary. How can I target and pull the shoe size number itself located between the < /button >?

Thanks!

[image: Inspected element of the button I want to interact with]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can locate the same size button on all pages with below XPath:

```
//button[@data-qa="size-dropdown" and .="9.5"]
```

You can also pass size as variable:

```
size = 9.5
xpath = '//button[@data-qa="size-dropdown" and .="%s"]' % size
```

If you need to extract all available sizes:

```
sizes = [boot.text for boot in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//button[@data-qa="size-dropdown"]')]
```

Comment: oh ok so it will be something like this :                                                                         size = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@data-qa="size-dropdown" and .="9.5"]').click()

Comment: `size = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@data-qa="size-dropdown" and .="9.5"]')` and `size.click()`

Comment: Everytime when I read any of your answers, I always learn someting new @sir Andersson. This usage is foreign to me.